# iText - ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed

Tags: java, exception, stream, itext

i'm trying to resize a pdf document, and then put a Stamp in each page.

I'm using Document for the resize and PdfStamper for the Stamp.

```
PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, output);
Document document = new Document();
```

The problem is when i close twice:  document.close() and stamp.close()
i'm getting the **ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed**

I know that this is because i'm closing both, document and stamp, but if i only close one, just the Object closed will work.

I don't know how to handle this.

Any ideas??
Thanks!

**EDIT - This is all the code i have for now:**

```
public void generateReducedPdf() throws Exception {

    //lectura del pdf a copiar
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("C:/Users/X30261GE/Downloads/ES_O00012741_2018_000000000000000000000000000153.pdf");
    int numberOfPages = reader.getNumberOfPages();

    Document document = new Document();

    //creación del nuevo pdf, junto con su ruta y nombre.

    FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/X30261GE/Downloads/pdfReducido.pdf");
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,  output);

    //PDF TIPO PDF/A1-b
    writer.setPDFXConformance(com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.PDFA1B);

    document.open();
    document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);

    PdfDictionary outi = new PdfDictionary(PdfName.OUTPUTINTENT);
    outi.put(PdfName.OUTPUTCONDITIONIDENTIFIER, new PdfString("sRGB IEC61966-2.1"));
    outi.put(PdfName.INFO, new PdfString("sRGB IEC61966-2.1"));
    outi.put(PdfName.S, PdfName.GTS_PDFA1);

    InputStream inst = ActionSignPdf.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/sRGB.profile");          
    com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ICC_Profile icc = ICC_Profile.getInstance(inst);

    PdfICCBased ib = new PdfICCBased(icc);
    ib.remove(PdfName.ALTERNATE);
    outi.put(PdfName.DESTOUTPUTPROFILE, writer.addToBody(ib).getIndirectReference());
    writer.getExtraCatalog().put(PdfName.OUTPUTINTENTS, new PdfArray(outi));

    PdfContentByte pdfContent = writer.getDirectContent();



    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++) {

        document.newPage();
        PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
        // Reducir las paginas al 80%
        pdfContent.addTemplate(page, .85f, 0, 0, .85f, 70, 110);



    }

    writer.createXmpMetadata();
    document.close();
    writer.close();


    //AHORA StAMP time
    //PRUEBA DE STAMP AQUI
    PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, output);
    PdfContentByte over;
    FontFactory.defaultEmbedding = true;
    FontFactory.register(ActionSignPdf.class.getResource("").getPath() + "Helvetica.ttf", ActionSignPdf.class.getResource("").getPath() + "Helvetica.ttf"); 
    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(ActionSignPdf.class.getResource("").getPath() + "Helvetica.ttf", BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    BaseFont bfNegrita = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.TIMES_BOLD, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);


    // mete el for
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++) {
    //PRUEBA DEL StAMP AQUI

        over = stamp.getOverContent(i);
        over.beginText();

        //set fuente negrita
        over.setFontAndSize(bfNegrita,8);

        //Primera linea
        //Coloco la primera parte en negrita
        int posLineaXNegrita = 150;

        over.showTextAligned(0, RegistroKeys.KEY_DIRECCION , posLineaXNegrita, 50, 0);
        //segunda parte

        //set fuente sin negrita
        over.setFontAndSize(bf,7);
        //posicion x donde colocare la segunda parte sin negrita

        int posLineaX = RegistroKeys.KEY_DIRECCION.length() + posLineaXNegrita + 108;
        over.setLineWidth(0);
        over.showTextAligned(0, RegistroKeys.KEY_DIRECCION_URL , posLineaX, 50, 0);

        //Siguiente linea
        //set fuente negrita
        over.setFontAndSize(bfNegrita,8);
        //primera parte en negrita
        posLineaXNegrita = 200;

        over.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_CENTER, RegistroKeys.KEY_CODIGO_SEGURO_DESCARGA, posLineaXNegrita, 40, 0);

        //segunda parte
        //set fuente sin negrita
        over.setFontAndSize(bf,7);
        //posicion x donde colocare la segunda parte sin negrita
        posLineaX = RegistroKeys.KEY_CODIGO_SEGURO_DESCARGA.length() + posLineaXNegrita + 105;
        String codigo =  "#002#9B4ECE66-A34D-3C0A-A6FA-6D67C31C9550";
        over.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_CENTER, codigo, posLineaX, 40, 0);
        over.endText();                 
        over.stroke(); 
    }
    stamp.close();
}
```

Like you say in comments, i'm trying to work with the stamp and the document in the same PDF, and that won't work.

I have to work first with document, and then with stamper.
Any ideas? thanks!

Comment: **A** You don't show the relevant code for your issue. **B** What you say, though, sounds like you try to simultaneously work on the same document using a `PdfReader`/`PdfStamper` and a `Document`/`?` combination. That obviously cannot work as you'll see if you think about it for a short time.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. You are right with B point. I think that i have work with the document first, and then, with the result of that, use the Stamper.
Now my question is, how to do that, how can i get a byte array from the output that is generated by the document.

Sorry if my post have nonsense, but i'm a noob in iText 

Thanks again friend.

Comment: Define 'if i only close one, just the Object closed will work.'

Comment: in my case, when I open PDF(encrypted) using PDFReader, the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

#### The actual issue

As it turned out in a comment, the actual question is

> I think that i have work with the document first, and then, with the result of that, use the Stamper. Now my question is, how to do that, how can i get a byte array from the output that is generated by the document.

You can get that by having the `Document`/`PdfWriter` couple write to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,  baos);
...
document.close();

...

PdfReader intermediary = new PdfReader(baos.toByteArray());
PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(intermediary, output);
...
stamp.close();
```

#### Further observations

- You appear to have multiple versions of iText in your classpath, in particular you use both classes from the `com.lowagie.text.pdf` and from `com.itextpdf.text.pdf` packages, i.e. from a version 5.x and from a version 4.2, 2.x, or older.

  Mixing different iText versions can result in weirdest effects. I'd propose you remove all older versions from your class path and only use the most current 5.x. As you call yourself a *a noob in iText*, you should even consider switching to iText 7.x unless you have a too large existing code base based on iText 5 to maintain.
- You use your `Document`/`Writer` pair only to copy pages from a `PdfReader reader` and set some PDF/A markers. You should consider to use a `Document`/`PdfCopy` pair or even a `PdfStamper` for this; your solution throws away all dynamic PDF structures (annotations, ...) and all document level data (metadata, ...).

  By the way, PDF/A is more than just some document settings, tere are a number of preconditions your source PDF must already fulfill, otherwise your output won't stand a PDF/A validation.